# What do the notations $\frac{O(n)}{O(n-1)}$ and $\frac{O(n)}{O(k) \times O(n-k)}$ mean?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, topological-groups

In the formulas:

$ 
\begin{align*}
S^{n-1} &\cong \frac{O(n)}{O(n-1)} \\
G(k,n) &\cong \frac{O(n)}{O(k) \times O(n-k)}
\end{align*}
$

what do the notations $\frac{O(n)}{O(n-1)}$ and $\frac{O(n)}{O(k) \times O(n-k)}$ mean? I know the definition of quotient topology, but in that case the denominator must be either a surjective function or an equivalence relation like $X / \sim$. But what does this notation mean when both numerator and denominator are spaces? (In the part of my book where these formulae were mentioned, they used terms like 'action of a group', 'transitive actions' - I read these terms on Wikipedia, but I can't see the relation between these terms and the above formulae.)

Comment: If $G$ is a group acting on a space $X$, then $X/G$ is defined to be the quotient by the equivalence relation where $x\sim g\cdot x$ for every $x\in X$ and $g\in G$.

Comment: This notation refers to a conventional embedding of $O(k)$ into $O(n)$, for $n>k$, by identifying orthogonal $k\times k$ matrices with matrices in $O(n)$ having a $k \times k$ block that is orthogonal, and the identity matrix for the complementary block.  This makes $O(k)$ a subgroup of $O(n)$, and the quotient is the group quotient.  Equivalently, the equivalence classes of the quotient are given by the orbits of the action of $O(k)$ on $O(n)$.

Comment: To put a name to it, these are [homogeneous spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_space).

Comment: I suggest you use the notation $G/H$ or $H\backslash G$ instead of $\frac{G}{H}$. While these quotients are indeed diffeomorphic, it's best to stick to the standard notations. For instance, $G/H$ means that you use the equivalence relation $x\sim x h$ for all $x\in G, h\in H$. The notation $H\backslash G$ will mean the equivalence relation $x\sim hx$ for all $x\in G, h\in H$.

Comment: @ElliotYu So $O(n-1)$ acts transitively on $O(n)$ and hence is a $O(n)$ is a homogenous space of $O(n-1)$? How does $S^{n-1}$ come into the picture though?

Comment: Actually it's $O(n)$ acting on $S^{n-1}$ transitively. The group $O(n-1)$ comes in as the stabilizer group of any given point in $S^{n-1}$. Alternatively, you can start with $O(n)$ and its subgroup $O(n-1)$, then you can construct the left coset space $O(n)/O(n-1)$, which ends up being the same as $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: There's also a theorem that says for any homogeneous $G$-space $M$, let $G_p\subset G$ be the stabilizer subgroup of any point $p\in M$, then the coset space $G/G_p$ and $M$ are diffeomorphic. This means that the two points of view above are really equivalent.